# Controlling a Servo motor

Tags: servo, wiring

I am having trouble running a servo motor with raspberry pi

Here is what I have done so far ,

I have gotten a servo motor (http://goo.gl/67AsF),

I have powered it with a 5 volt power source from a battery,

I am trying to send a PWM with a raspberry pi (Model B rev 1) using the wiring pi library,

GPIO port 18 gives out about 3v power, I am using it send the pwm ([code](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/examples/servo.c)) , But the motor isn't moving .

What am I doing wrong ? what do I do to fix it ?

Comment: I suggest the first thing you try is to follow the Adafruit tutorial example at: http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/01/09/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-8-using-a-servo-motor-raspberry_pi-raspberrypi/

Comment: Did you connect the ground wires together?

Comment: @recantha : I followed the same tutorial, It didnt work.

Comment: @gnibbler : Yes :-) , of course

Comment: Did you connect the grounds from the battery to the ground of the Pi? I only ask because I thought I had connected the ground wires together and then realised it didn't just mean the motor grounds. :-)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you try the command ```sudo i2cdetect -y 1```? It should print a little chart with some numbers on it if it detects a device. I get nothing when I wire up a servo according to the Adafruit example, but the LED backpack works, so i2c isn't totally fried.